# C++ Program Not Relying on Virtual Memory

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

A homework assignment I am working on requires that we exhaust our main memory so that the program uses virtual memory so that we can observe and measure the slowdown. However, when I get to sufficiently large memory values, I segfault or crash. I need to exhaust main memory and use virtual memory simultaneously and I was under the impression that windows (or other operating systems) would just take care of this, at least that is how it has been portrayed to me. The program I am using to observe this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int sizes[] = { 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768, 65536 };

using namespace std::chrono;

int main(int c, char** args)
{
    int** A;
    int** B;
    int** C;
    for (int n : sizes)
    {
        A = new int*[n];
        B = new int*[n];
        C = new int*[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            A[i] = new int[n];
            B[i] = new int[n];
            C[i] = new int[n];
        }
        milliseconds pre_add1 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
            }
        }
        milliseconds post_add1 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
        milliseconds pre_add2 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                C[i][j] = A[i][j] + B[i][j];
            }
        }
        milliseconds post_add2 = duration_cast<milliseconds>(system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            delete A[i];
            delete B[i];
            delete C[i];
        }
        delete A;
        delete B;
        delete C;
        std::cout << "Size " << n << " took " << (post_add1 - pre_add1).count() << " ms for addition 1" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size " << n << " took " << (post_add2 - pre_add2).count() << "ms for addition 2" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `operator new`, you may want to use the Windows API for allocating dynamic memory.

Comment: Are you referring to something other than malloc? Because the microsoft documentation has both new( [] ) and malloc, I've tried both and had problems with both.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to other memory allocation than `malloc` or `new`.  Windows has API where you can allocate memory from the operating system.  Search the internet for "MSDN memory allocation API c++".

Comment: In particular look at VirtualAlloc (HeapAlloc is a somewhat more capable heap than the that offered by the MSVC run-time library while GlobalAlloc and LocalAlloc are mostly historic footnotes at this point and should not be used if they can be avoided).

Comment: You could simply do `char *p=malloc (100000000000L)`. That will allocate uncommitted virtual memory. Then start writing 0's to it. That will allocate physical memory and once that's exhausted will start paging.

Comment: You may want to increase the size of your page file, so that `new` doesn't fail so quickly. For Windows 7, see [this link](https://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Windows-7-virtual-memory-performance-optimization) on how to increase the page file size.

Comment: Ultimately my pagefile was just not large enough, I was underestimating the other things on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) should have a corresponding call to [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) and every call to `new[]` should have a corresponding call to `delete[]`.

By instead calling `delete` on a memory block that was allocated with `new[]`, you are causing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is likely the reason for your crash.

To fix the problem, you must change the lines

```
delete A[i];
delete B[i];
delete C[i];
```

to

```
delete[] A[i];
delete[] B[i];
delete[] C[i];
```

and the lines

```
delete A;
delete B;
delete C;
```

to

```
delete[] A;
delete[] B;
delete[] C;
```

Also, you may want to increase the size of your page file, so that `new` doesn't fail so quickly. For Windows 7, see [this link](https://searchitchannel.techtarget.com/feature/Windows-7-virtual-memory-performance-optimization) on how to increase the page file size.